# TypeError: test_Login() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'username' and 'password'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to the python and working on python 3.4.3. While executing below code received error :
    test_Login() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'username' and 'password'

Please could you help?

Below is my script:

```
 @pytest.mark.usefixtures("oneTimeSetup","setUp")
 @ddt
 class ATS_Login(unittest.TestCase):
   log = CL.customLogger(logging.DEBUG)

   @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
   def classsetup(self, oneTimeSetup, setUp):
      self.AL=ATS_Login_page(self.driver)
      self.LO = ATS_Logout_page(self.driver)
      self.LD=ATS_Leaves(self.driver)
      self.SV=ATS_SalarySlip(self.driver)

  @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
  @data(*getcredentials("C:\\Users\\HP\\PycharmProjects\\ATS\\utilities\\testdata.csv"))
  @unpack
  def test_Login(self,username,password):
     self.AL.login(username,password)
```

Below is content of testdata.csv

```
 username,password

 rupesh.doshi@gmail.com,rupesh
```

Comment: What exactly does your get credentials do..?? Looks like it's not returning any value..

Comment: Actually program runs as below             . It will take credentials from file 
    testdata.csv and  it will pass test_login(self,username,password) method. Then 
    it will call self.AL.Login method defined in another class with same username 
    and password and will loggin into the application. The program will not return 
   any value it will just pass the parameter username and password from file 
   testdata.csv.

Comment: For your code to work your getcredentials method has to return a tuple containing (username, password)

Comment: Thanks Akash for your feedback. Please could you let me know how to return a tuple?